# Auto Completion for facebook friends?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

After taking all the required privileges from a user I want to display a text box where the user type his friend name and get assisted by auto-helper type functionality which shows related friends name .

I think only way is FQL but query with 'Like abc%' is not supported also joining of table is not possible then how can I achieve this type of functionality .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to get all their friends and browse through them

You need to have read_friendlists  permissions and issue a GET request to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...`

Comment: no I don't want to do that since a user can have 1000 friends then storing all those friends first is not an ideal solution for me.

Comment: you could request offline_access and have a cron process all the users friends.

Comment: @beginner: sorry, but I think that's the only way.

Comment: @Lix: Hmm, that's a bad idea if user is just going around and trying to find other friends. I'd think OP wants to get it immediately. I'd suggest OP to download all these friends, no matter how many are there.

Comment: @Lix user friends is a variable thing which keeps changing with time hence cannot be cached for longtime .

Comment: @beginner: that's why he said you can cron it, to kindly check it every hour for example

Comment: Well you are trying to mimick facebook behaviour - obviously you will not be able to get it working as well as it is on faecbook.com - I agree that a cron might not be the best solution, but it is a suggestion.  I dont believe you will be able to get away from pre-loading all the users friends.

Comment: I've done this and its very quick as friends are not paginated. I used Jquery for the autocomplete. All good.